# Python URL Not Found

Tags: python, django

I am using [this](https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/create-the-hello-world-web-app/?trim=yes) Python tutorial but looks like the author hasn't updated it because the code is using deprecated Python code, specifically:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^hello-world/$', index),
    )
```

I looked up Django documentation and other StackOverFlow questions but I am unable to resolve how I can use the current method.  This is what I have added to replace the above:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello-world$', hello),
]
```

And here is the full hello.py file:

```
import sys

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='thisisabadkeybutitwilldo',
    ROOT_URLCONF=sys.modules[__name__],
)

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World')

import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello-world$', hello),
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And this is the error message I get from Python:

> Using the URLconf defined in **main**, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: ^$ [name='hello'] The current URL, hello,
>   didn't match any of these.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't work at all and it definitely doesn't raise that error. When I make any necessary changes it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as provided, does not work. I tested the code from the linked tutorial, and it works fine in 1.8. Your code has a random import(`import views`) and an undefined variable(`hello`). So I made the logical edits to your code and tested it and it's fine in 1.11:

```
import sys

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY='thisisabadkeybutitwilldo',
    ROOT_URLCONF=sys.modules[__name__],
)

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hello-world$', index),
]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I just need to use 'index' instead of 'hello' on this line: url(r'^hello-world$', hello),

Comment: No problem. Yea, I figured that was the desired name, but changed it to `index` instead since that was the first one I saw.